# How do you take back the beach in the Costal Run level of Call of Duty: Black Ops for the DS?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops, nintendo-ds

I'm playing it through on the hardest difficulty, but I can't beat this part. I've tried exhausting all of my sniper rifle ammo from the rock on the the cliff that you start on to no avail, and running around the edge to see if you have to climb up something.

My brother beat it on an easier difficulty and said that you just have to shoot them while in the pit-like area, and eventually you'll be rescued. The pause screen seems to confirm this, but how long does it take?

Do you have to kill a certain number or wait a certain time? How many/long? Also, how far down do you have to go? I've tried hiding behind the first rock and unloading a couple of PPSh-41's, but I still didn't win.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally beat it. The first rock on the beach is far enough down, and I only had to kill two waves of Cubans. My problem was that I was crouching behind the rock. You apparently have to stand behind the rock, so the helicopter can see you.

Answer (score -1):

First you need to have a ppsh-41 And a scoped rifle.then you have to kill the Basoca Guy then you quickly go the the rock. And stand there for a while. Then your object is complet.and you have to shot the helicopter to see you.and On more thing be in a safety place where the helicopter can shoot two missle's.

Comment: This was already answered and accepted years ago.